# How to display table footer in table header group in IE

Tags: jquery, css, html, internet-explorer

I am using this css:

```
tfoot {
display: table-header-group;
}
```

and it works perfectly in Google Chrome. Internet Explorer shows tfoot in the bottom. Any solution to this?

Comment: Please provide some more code

Comment: Build a complete working example (otherwise it's hard to help). you can use jsfiddle.net for that.

Comment: I want to do pretty much like here: https://jsfiddle.net/a6565umd/.

To show the search boxes on the header but IE refuses to take this css and keeps showing tfoot at the end of the table.